# How to set code behind properties in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, properties

Is it possible to set a property of the code behind using javascript?

I have the following:

```
private string dateFormat;
public string DateFormat
{
    get
    {
        return dateFormat;
    }
    set
    {
        dateFormat = value;
    }
}
```

and want to set it like this: `'<%=DateFormat%>' = "dd-mm-YYYY"`

But when I run this and add a debbugger it comes out like this: '' = "dd-mm-YYYY".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without quotes:

```
var <%=DateFormat%> = "dd-mm-YYYY";
```

but in your case the property does not have a value so you should check if it is set.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly; you need to use an [ASP.NET hidden field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) which will then return the value to your code on a postback, and persist it across multiple postbacks.

The C# would be like

```
public string DateFormat
{
    get
    {
        return DateFormatField.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        DateFormatField.Value = value;
    }
}
```

The JavaScript to set it would be something like

```
document.getElementById('<%=DateFormatField.ClientID%>').value = 'dd-mm-YYYY';
```